# An operator equation $ AXB=CX+XD $

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $A,B,C,D\in M$ be self-adjoint.
My question is about the following equation:
$$ AXB=CX+XD, ~\forall X\in M.$$

In the case when $M$ is $B(H)$, it is known that the above equation implies that either $A,C$ are scalars or else $B,D$ are scalars (see [Lemma 2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123681900380?via%3Dihub)). For the case when $M$ is a semifinite factor (see [Theorem 3.1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01229507)), the same result holds true.

I am wondering what can we say about the case when $M$ is not a factor (say, $M$ is semifinite or just finite). My conjecture is: there exists a central projection $z\in M$ such that either $Az,Cz, B(1-z), D(1-z)$ are in the center of $M$.

I am not sure whether there are any known results on such an equation.